# How open facebook app on specific profile using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

i was tried everything, but nothing work. it always show me the main view on facebook app.
This is my code

```
window.open(`fb://{profile}`, '_blank')
```

I tried with other possibilities such as

- fb://profile/{userID}
- fb://page/{id}

But nothing work. Can you help me!!!

Comment: I think you mean window.open(`fb://${profile}`, '_blank')

Comment: i use "{}" only to show that inside must go de profile  , i tried this 
window.open (`fb: // faceweb / f? href = $ {encodeURI (` https://www.facebook.com/$ {profile} `)}`, '_blank') and worked, but only in android, i need it worked on ios too. Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution

```
android: window.open(`fb://faceweb/f?href=${encodeURI(`https://www.facebook.com/${profile}`)}`, '_blank')

ios: window.open(`fb://profile?id=${profile}`, '_blank')
```

Tested Nov. 2020

Comment: perfect, works great on iOS 15 (Feb 2022).